# Optimizing slow query that uses concat in the order by clause

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm having difficulties on a query that does several joins, and is very slow for large recordsets.  Here is the query:

```
SELECT 
    order_headers.*,
    SUM(order_details.cost) AS amount,
    CONCAT(organizations.card_first_name,
            ' ',
            organizations.card_last_name) AS card_name
FROM
    order_headers
        INNER JOIN
    organizations ON order_headers.organization_id = organizations.id
        LEFT JOIN
    order_details ON order_details.order_header_id = order_headers.id
        LEFT JOIN
    user_accounts ON user_accounts.organization_id = organizations.id
        AND organizations.is_single_user = 1
WHERE
    (status IN ('UNCHARGED' , 'ERROR'))
GROUP BY order_headers.id
HAVING SUM(order_details.cost) > 0
ORDER BY IF(organizations.is_single_user = 1,
    (user_accounts.first_name + ' ' + user_accounts.last_name),
    organizations.name) ASC
LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0
```

There are a few things I can remove from the query (although are needed for my app to function), that speed up the query to ~0.183 sec.  Those include:

1. Remove the order by clause entirely.  For some reason MySQL doesn't like
   pulling in fields from the user_accounts table.  But this means I can't sort by first/last name.  Just removing the concatenation isn't enough, I have to remove first AND last from the order clause to get any performance gain.  One option I've considered is "caching" the user first/last name in the organizations.name field.  However, running the query ordering by organizations.name alone, is also non-performant.  And I'd have to refactor my application code.
2. Remove all references, inclusions of the order_details table (this
   is actually our biggest table at around 101K records).  But then I don't have a sum of the order details, and I'm not limiting the results to those order_headers with sum > 0.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a conditional `ORDER BY` clause that seems to be unnecessary. Your `JOIN` on `user_accounts` is specifying only `organizations` where `is_single_user = 1`. But you are using that as part of your `ORDER BY` conditional. `is_single_user = 1` in this case will always be true.

So try this revised `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT 
    order_headers.*,
    SUM(order_details.cost) AS amount,
    CONCAT(organizations.card_first_name,
            ' ',
            organizations.card_last_name) AS card_name
FROM
    order_headers
        INNER JOIN
    organizations ON order_headers.organization_id = organizations.id
        LEFT JOIN
    order_details ON order_details.order_header_id = order_headers.id
        LEFT JOIN
    user_accounts ON user_accounts.organization_id = organizations.id
        AND organizations.is_single_user = 1
WHERE
    (status IN ('UNCHARGED' , 'ERROR'))
GROUP BY order_headers.id
HAVING SUM(order_details.cost) > 0
ORDER BY user_accounts.first_name, user_accounts.last_name
LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0
```

Second, make sure you have indexes set up on all your foreign keys (the ones you're joining on) and maybe on `user_accounts.first_name + user_accounts.last_name` to help with the sorting.

Comment: It's a left join, so organisations with is_single_user=0 will still be included.